# Android Architechture Component LiveData Data change

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

I have started to work on android architecture component introduced recently.

```
DataLiveList.getPhotoDataList().observe(PhotosFragmentNew.this, new Observer<List<PhotoDataLive>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable List<PhotoDataLive> photoDataLives)    {

        } 

    });
```

My problem is i just want the last added element not the list of all the items in database, second i want to know auto generated id for new model, what is best way to get that id while inserting element.

Comment: Observe the list… keep it sorted… get the first (or last). or… publish the last as a LiveData<OnePhoto> instead of a list… or… so many other ways you could approach that, and It doesn’t have much to do with LiveData per se. Additionally, for the “autogenerated id” have a `@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)` and … just read it!

Comment: Thanks yup got it.. posting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing it wrong as my method

```
DataLiveList.getPhotoDataList()
```

Returns a list, that is my DAO class has query of select * from PhotoModel, I just had to write another method in DAO class

```
@Query("Select * from photomodel order by Id desc limit 1")
LiveData<photomodel> getLatestAddedItem();
```

and now when i change following

```
DataLiveList.getPhotoDataList().observe(PhotosFragmentNew.this, new Observer<List<PhotoDataLive>>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(@Nullable List<PhotoDataLive> photoDataLives)    {

    } 

});
```

To

```
DataLiveList.getLatestAddedItem().observe(PhotosFragmentNew.this, new Observer<PhotoDataLive>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(@Nullable PhotoDataLive photoDataLives)    {

    } 

});
```

This will result into what i wanted